# Seekbar focus not wanted

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am using a SeekBar in my layout and I have another View that is a RelativeLayout.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>
    ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/progressSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="70"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/player_seek_bar_progress"/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

And when I touch this RelativeLayout, the SeekBar gains the focus...
I don't find any problem in my layout even in my code...

Does someone have the same issue?

Thanks guys for your answers :)

Comment: did you solve this problem ? how ?

Comment: @RasoolGhana I answered this question a few days ago. Maybe this is useful to you. :)

Answer (score 7):

I've just had the exact same problem.
My layout looks something like the following (I omitted irrelevant views for this topic). As you can see, both the parent view (the `LinearLayout`) and the `SeekBar` have `android:clickable="true"` property.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## How to solve it? :]

Here's what I've found in the source code for `#android.view.ViewGroup#dispatchSetPressed` (this is the event that gets called each time the user touches the screen)

It loops through every child view, and if it matches the following condition, it propagates the event to this child view:

```
if (!pressed || (!child.isClickable() && !child.isLongClickable())) {  
  child.setPressed(pressed); 
}
```

Basically, if your child view (in this case, the `SeekBar` is either clickable or long clickable, you will not propagate the event to it.
In addition, there's a comment that says the following:

> Children that are clickable on their own should not show a pressed
>   state when their parent view does. Clearing a pressed state always
>   propagates.

The situation this comment is describing is the same as you are facing right now. If you set the `SeekBar` as clickable, Android knows that is has to react to click events directly in the `SeekBar`, and it will not propagate the event.

This worked for me. Hope it will work for you too.

### Reference

[ViewGroup source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java)

Comment: This is genious, but that Android behaves this way is super counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/progressSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="70"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/player_seek_bar_progress"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: hmmm... Another thing to try would be to wrap the `SeekBar` in another `ViewGroup` like a `FrameLayout` and set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on it.  If the `RelativeLayout` has a view like an `EditText` that you want to have the focus instead, you could try putting `<requestFocus/>` on that.

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: Can you post your complete layout XML?

Answer (score 0):

```
mSeekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressSeekBar);
mSeekBar.setFocusable(false);
```

Have you tried programmatically setting your SeekBar? This seemed to work for me, but setting the XML attribute to `android:focusable="false"` did not.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in root view and remove any clickable in root

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` as a SeekBar XML attributes. After doing so the SeekBar will not get focus when you click on parent layout.

Credits to @Kashmir

```
    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="true" 
            android:focusable="true"

            />
```

Answer (score 0):

i have seekBar inside my frameLayout
i have done this programatically & it worked for me :

```
seekbar.isClickable = true
```